# Three figures on the same page, with captions

Tags: floats

I want to have a dedicated page for all my figures,  so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1789770/2169327) advice to ensure this. However, only one caption shows, instead of three. Am I doing something wrong? Is there an alternative way?

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{ramsstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
\restylefloat{figure}
     \begin{document}
            \begin{figure}[p]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig1}
                \caption{Capt1.}
                \label{fig:lab1}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig2}
                \caption{Capt2.}
                \label{fig:lab2}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig3}
                \caption{capt3.}
                \label{fig:lab3}
            \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Honestly It is kind of hard to make a MWE, as this error isn't reproducible, as is shown by my link to the answer on an other question. There is no indication on why this does not work. I'll do my best to update

Comment: `\usepackage{caption}` is twice there... `ramsstyle`? Is that a package or a typo? But the main cause is `\restylefloat{figure}` If you remove it, there will be 3 captions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*One* `\centering` is enough. You are loading `caption` twice, the second one is useless.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig1}
        \caption{Capt1.}    \label{fig:lab1}
        \bigskip%% To get some more space after the caption
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig2}
        \caption{Capt2.}    \label{fig:lab2}
        \bigskip
        \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig3}
        \caption{capt3.}    \label{fig:lab3}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`\restylefloat` from `float` package does some redefinitions to the way how `figure` or `table` are presented. This isn't compatible with `caption` or `subcaption` package. Since `caption` is more up-to-date than `float` there's no need for `\restylefloat`). And in my opinion, `float` isn't needed here at all.

(the `ramsstyle` package has to be commented out)

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{report}
%\usepackage{ramsstyle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
%\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig1}
  \caption{Capt1.}
  \label{fig:lab1}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig2}
  \caption{Capt2.}
  \label{fig:lab2}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig/fig3}
  \caption{capt3.}
  \label{fig:lab3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]